# using PDB, F11 steps into the code but F12 cannot browse it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, pdb-files

I am quite new to Visual Studio so don't know if I am doing something wrong or if this really is the way it is supposed to work.

In my "application" project, I am adding reference to a DLL, for which I have the sources. I add reference the the dll in a folder that also has the pdb file.

Now if I debug the application project I am able to step into (<kbd>F11</kbd>) the dll code and VS opens the correct .cs file. But if I am not debugging, pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> only opens a **..[From Metadata]** window.

Is there a way to browse the code when not debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you step-into the debugger uses the PDB file.  When you press <kbd>F12</kbd> Visual-Studio uses the Intellisense database which scans only files in the solution.   Files you see as [From Metadata] are referenced but do not have the source in the solution.

Comment: Thanks John. I guess your answer is that "no, there is no way to browse the code then not debugging", I wish VS was smart enough to do this.